# How to open results in another page

Tags: javascript

This is probably a simple question but I cannot figure out how to open the results from my database in a javascript popup window. I have an index.php page with a input box and an input button. When the user selects a date and presses the button, I'd like the results to open in a new window. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest not doing this — http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_16_not_opening_new_windows.html — but if you insist, then:

```
<form action="…" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simple html:

```
<a href="some.htm" target="_new">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Umar. I know I can use target for a link but what about a input button? There is no target attribute for this. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Targets must start with a letter unless they are one of a short list of reserved names that begin with an underscore … and don't include _new. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your new window using window.open. What you could do, is pass the date in as a querystring parameter to the URL that makes up the popup window page, and then use that parameter to perform the lookup from the database.

[This](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) page shows how to use window.open.

Comment: Thank you Pete. I will have a look there now.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open to open another window. And than use this window to document.body.innerHTML your data.[example](http://jsbin.com/iqezi)

```
var wnd=window.open('','newWnd'); 
wnd.document.body.innerHTML="test"
```